# How can I write a frame of an embedded YouTube video (via iframe) to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, youtube-javascript-api

I'd like to be able to extract frames from YouTube videos at various points within them (not just at the thumbnails), and do some processing on them. I can embed the video in my website using the iframe API, but I am struggling to find a way to capture that to a canvas. (It's ok if I am forced to capture the entire screen, and ok if I have to make changes to browser settings to allow it.)

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as Stack Overflow is not a code writing service*). Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [mcve] and also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not asking for code to be written, but I am asking for a general approach, as this problem is complicated by the security issue of iframes so it isn't all that straightforward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to write a browser extension. But I would guess you would want to avoid that.

The other option is to use the Screen Capture API (which is supported in Chrome, Edge and Firefox). Check out the [browser compatibility information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API#Browser_compatibility) on MDN.

Using this API, you can allow your user to share his screen or browser tab and play this on a transient video element:

```
const videoElem = document.createElement('video');
videoElem.autoplay = true;

const displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "never"
  },
  audio: false
};

async function startCapture() {
  videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices
    .getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
}
```

Later you can draw the video on a canvas to get a Base64 frame (basically a screenshot).

```
function getScreenshotInBase64() {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let [w, h] = [videoElem.videoWidth, videoElem.videoHeight];
  canvas.width =  w;
  canvas.height = h;
  context.drawImage(videoElem, 0, 0, w, h);
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Limitations with this approach:

- The user may select a different tab / application / screen or the page may be scrolled down and the video not visible.
- You get more than just the video (but based on your description, this is not necessarily bad).
- Pretty scarce browser support (if you consider older or mobile browsers).
- The user has to allow you to do it (basically each time you want to start sharing = recording the video in your case).

I build a small JsFiddle with the above snippets, which gets a Base64 print screen 2 seconds after you start screen sharing (by clicking the start button): https://jsfiddle.net/75Lmbf2o/.

Comment: This should work. It says I can't award a bounty for 22 hours, I'll come back tomorrow and it is yours.  You saved me a lot of time figuring that out, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Firefox 66 supports the Screen Capture API as well, and there's a [polyfill](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/q75yb8pf/) available for older versions.

Comment: @jib: Thanks for the hint; I updated the answer accordingly. I somehow managed to misread the compatibility table initially :|

Comment: @SerbanPetrescu You didn't. I updated it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks again.  Did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: hey, how to do it with an browser extension?:)

Comment: Depends on the browser. For example, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/